# Getting TestNG error after import Maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, testng

I have imported one Maven project for automated test cases. I am getting the error  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.testng.TestRunner.addListener(Ljava/lang/Object;)V

when run the test case

I have tried by reinstalling TestNG in eclipse

ava.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.testng.TestRunner.addListener(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_9_10$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_9_10.java:32)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_9_10$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_9_10.java:61)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:713)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:260)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.(SuiteRunner.java:198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1295)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1273)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1128)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)

Comment: Please edit your question and add details pertaining to "What version of TestNG do you have as a maven dependency?" and "What version of eclipse TestNG plugin are you working with" ?

Comment: Thanks. The problem was caused due the higher version of testng maven dependancy.

Comment: Can you add this as an answer and accept it so that the question gets closed ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. The problem was caused due the higher version of testng maven dependancy